# How to get count of distinct values from two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, distinct

There are two tables. 1st: **blogCategories**, 2nd: **blog**.
Table **blogCategories** has just 2 fields, id and categoyName. There are many category names inserted before. Table **blog** has id, blogCatID, header, blog, date fileds. 
There are many records in table **blog**. But not all categoryName's were used. 
I try to get a list of categoryNames with their count of uses in blogs. I need 0 (zero) if categoryName is not used in blog.

I used the query below. But categoryNames gets count number 1 even if they have not been used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoryName, COUNT(*) AS totalBlogCount
FROM
    (SELECT bc.categoryName
    FROM
        blogCategories bc
        LEFT JOIN blog b ON bc.id=b.blogCatID) AS tot
GROUP BY categoryName
```

Comment: So a blog can only have one category?

Comment: Yes. Just one category id for blogCatID (Int) field.

Comment: Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams this solves my problem like a charm :) I need to learn sql seriously! Thank you.

Comment: I just edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: @caglaror check my answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983093/1530742).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below query will give you the categoryName and count of usage. if no usage then it will return `0` as `count(null value)=0`

```
SELECT bc.categoryName, COUNT(b.blogCatID) AS totalBlogCount 
FROM blogCategories bc Left JOIN blog b ON bc.id=b.blogCatID
GROUP BY categoryName
```

output will looks like

```
inspirational 5
technical 2
political 0
random 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select bc.CategoryName, NullIf(bCounts.NumberOfTimesUsed,0) As NumberOfTimesUsedInBlog
From BlogCategories bc
Left Join
(Select blogCatID, Count(*) as NumberOfTimesUsed
From Blog Group By BlogCatID) bCounts
On bCounts.BlogCatID = bc.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bc.categoryName, COUNT(*) AS totalBlogCount 
FROM blogCategories bc INNER JOIN blog b ON bc.id=b.blogCatID
GROUP BY categoryName
```

Comment: Not sure whether you are right or I am, depends on whether 0 for categories not in blog is required. :(

Comment: Ah yes, hadn't thought of that; +1

Answer (score 1):

First you count the used blogCatID:

```
select blogCatID, count(*) as Number
from blog
group by blogCatID
```

later on you can find out which blogCategories are not used:

```
select *
from blogCategories as bc
where bc.id not in (select blogCatID
    from blog
    group by blogCatID)
```

next try a list of blogCategories together with the count of usage in blogs (and 0 if not used):

```
select isnull(b.numb, 0) as num, bc.*
from blogCategories as bc left join (select blogCatID, count(*) as numb
    from blog
    group by blogCatID) as b ON bc.id b.blogCatID
```

Comment: I need 0 even if not in select blogCatID
    from blog
    group by blogCatID